# Pyside-uic for python3?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside

Is there pyside-uic version which generates code for python 3? In Ubuntu repos there is pyside for both python 2 and 3, but pyside-tools (package which contains pyside-uic) is only available for pyside for python2.

And if there isn't python3 version, is there any other tool for pyside which can generate python 3 code? Everything I know can only generate python 2 code.

Comment: You could try to use the `uic` for python2 and the use `2to3` to convert it to python3.

Comment: @Bakuriu lol I didn't know about 2to3. That will make my life much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is pyside-uic which generates the code for python 3, but it fails to install because of install script bug. it will be fixed and released soon

**Update 1:**
problem was in distribute script not in pyside install script. I have fixed distribute and created pull request, until the fix is merged to official distribute and released, you can use my distribute clone from here https://bitbucket.org/rlacko/distribute

**Update 2:**
the fix was merged to official distribute and released in version 0.6.36

Comment: could you tell me where can I find pyside-uic for python3 source or static linux binary? Because in ubuntu repos pyside3-tools won't appear, they ignore my request.

Comment: you can follow the instructions on how to compile and install PySide  from source on linux here [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#id32], the resulting PySide package (standard python egg) will contain also pyside-uic. You can install this package with easy_install.

Comment: this is the right link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#building-pyside-distribution-egg and dont forget to install prerequisities https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#id1